# Flickering when using Scrollify

Tags: jquery-scrollify

I seem to be encountering issues when attempting to scroll between a regular scrollify panel and interstitialSection. I need to add the elements within the interstitialSection to the standardScrollElements as they need to be scrollable.

When you scroll quickly on a desktop there is flickering and when using a mobile it exhibits other issues like not enabling scrollify on scrolling. When you clear the 'StandardScrollElements' it stops the flickering but doesn't allow scrolling of the content on the slide mainly on mobile.

```
    $.scrollify({
        section: ".slide",
        scrollbars: true,
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        scrollSpeed: 800,
        updateHash: false,
        standardScrollElements: ".footer-content,.news",
        interstitialSection: ".slide-content,.clients,footer",
        before: function () {
        },
        after: function (i) {
            $.scrollify.current().find("[data-animated]").each(function () {
                var animClass = $(this).attr("data-animated");
                $(this).addClass("animated");
                $(this).addClass(animClass);
            });
        },
        afterRender: function () {
            $.scrollify.current().find("[data-animated]").each(function () {
                var animClass = $(this).attr("data-animated");
                $(this).addClass("animated");
                $(this).addClass(animClass);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I replaced Scrollify with Fullpage.js.